# Android Java: EditText text-selection is missing context-menu

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext, dialog

so I'm currently writing an android-application that opens a dialog with an inflated custom view.

That custom view contains an EditText (multilined, so you can enter a longer message text). If a user enters a longer text message and tries to select some words of that text afterwards, it doesnt show the context-menu (menu for copy, paste, and so on):

[image: As you can see I can select some text, but the context menu does not show.]

When I dont select anything, and just tap'n'hold  on the text, the context-menu appears automatically.

[image]

This is my layout-code:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/Caption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/L_RepostCaptionDialog_TextAreaHint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLength="2199"
            android:maxLines="12"
            android:minHeight="120dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textColorHint="#999999"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="11.5dp" />
```

I have the same EditText and the same functionality on a different activity - and it works perfectly. The only difference is, that one of them is in a Dialog (doesnt work), and the other one is in an Activity (works fine).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.